# Como implementar "Up Navigation" dinâmico?

Tags: android

Estou tentando implementar **[Up Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)** em meu aplicativo Android mas aparentemente, não encontrei nenhuma forma de fazer que `android:parentActivityName`, setado no *manifest*, possa ser manipulado em tempo de execução.

O que acontece em meu caso é que, por exemplo, tenho uma Activity de pesquisa de Cidades, que pode ser chamada a partir de varias Activity's, sendo que ao clicar no ícone de "UP Navigation", seria necessário voltar para a Activity anterior (a que chamou a Activity de pesquisa), e não para a Activity setada em `android:parentActivityName`, sendo que esse comportamento deveria ser dinâmico, e não pre-configurado no *manifest*

**Existe alguma forma de tornar esse comportamento dinâmico**, por exemplo, buscando a última Activity da pilha?

O que implementei até o momento é isso:

No *manifest*:

```xml
<activity
    android:name="com.myapp.SearchCityActivity"
    android:parentActivityName="com.myapp.MainActivity" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.myapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

No `onCreate()` da Activity de pesquisa:

```java
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

E estou sobrescrevendo o método `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```java
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
        if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
            TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                 .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
                 .startActivities();
        } else {
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Há algo a mais que eu possa fazer para chegar ao comportamento esperado?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quer simplesmente sair da Activity de pesquisa e voltar para a Activity que à chamou, depois que o usuário clicar no ícone do Up Navigation finalize a Activity de pesquisa.

```
this.finish();
```

Não sei se pelo que entendi é isso que você quer...

Comment: Não era bem isso que eu queria, mas essa simples abordagem funciona para o meu caso, não havia pensado de maneira simplificada. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Há real necessidade do uso de parentActivityName?
Não seria melhor deixar sua activity de busca de cidades sem este recurso? Já que você tem que voltar para a activity que chamou sua SearchCityActivity.

Comment: é necessário para manter o padrão de navegação dentro do aplicativo, pois estou implementando esse tipo de navegação em todos as Activity's, só estou com problemas nesses casos.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que você consegue fazer isso no seu método onOptionsItemSelected() e fazer um switch case para o id do icone de Home na ActionBar. Eu poderia ter feito isso em um projeto meu da forma que vou te apresentar, mas atento a observação que eu usei Activitys e Fragments, minha navegação era quase toda por Fragments. Eu não declarei o atributo android:parentActivityName nem o  no manifesto.

Eu simplesmente implementei o case do menu assim:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.home:
            // é aqui que você volta para a activity ou fragment anterior
            Intent parentActivityIntent = new Intent(this, SuaActivityAnterior.getClass() );
            // Remove todas as outras activitys que estão na pilha
            parentActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(parentActivityIntent);
            finish();
            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Estou utilizando Activity's

Comment: @Fernando editei meu post com talvez uma possível solução e como eu implementaria.